# MBCalendarKit not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mbcalendarkit

i have followed as per instruction to use MBCalendarKit into my app but it doesn't seem to be working . I am posting my code below in swift .

```
import UIKit
 class ViewController: CKCalendarViewController, CKCalendarViewDelegate , CKCalendarViewDataSource {
var data : NSMutableDictionary

override init() {
self.data = NSMutableDictionary()
super.init()
  }
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
data = NSMutableDictionary()
super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

self.data = NSMutableDictionary()
super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
//  Step 0 : Wire up the data source and delegate
self.delegate = self
self.dataSource = self

//  Step 1 : Define some events

 let title : NSString = NSLocalizedString("Add Swift Demo", comment: "")
 let date : NSDate = NSDate(day: 9, month: 1, year: 2015)
 let event : CKCalendarEvent = CKCalendarEvent(title: title, andDate: date, andInfo: nil)

//  Step 2 : Add the events to the cache array
self.data[date] = [event]
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
//  MARK: - CKCalendarDataSource
func calendarView(calendarView: CKCalendarView!, eventsForDate date: NSDate!) -> [AnyObject]! {
return self.data.objectForKey(date) as [AnyObject]!
}
override func calendarView() -> CKCalendarView! {
return CKCalendarView()
}
}
```

"
install mbcalendarKit . instruction can be found over here https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit

also i think the problem is with podfile but that doesn't seem to be the issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: there are currently no errors and build succeeds

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: i built mine own custom calendar

Comment: Oh well. I'm the developer behind MBCalendarKit, so if you need anything, just holler.